# pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['x']) just creates the same column 'x' again as dummies column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `df['x']` with values 1, 0 and NaN.

After running

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['x'])
```

I get just 'x_1.0' with same values. 'x' dtype is float64.

Is it dropping the first column with 0s? Also how can I drop rows that have NaN in column 'x'.

Thanks

Comment: try `df.dropna()` more information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you wan to drop `nan` values in column `x`, otherwise your use of `get_dummies` is wrong as there are no categorical variables in column `x`

To drop `nan` values you can use:

```
df.dropna(subset = ["x"], inplace=True)
```